# Azure - Push Notifications - Failed to send test message

Tags: c#, azure, push-notification, uwp, azure-notificationhub

In Azure i have created a sample notification hub and tried to send test Toast notification for windows. And i ended up with below exception in Azure.

Failed to send test message. Error: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":{\"message\":\"Bad Request\",\"code\":\"BadRequest\"}}","responseJSON":{"error":{"message":"Bad Request","code":"BadRequest"}},"status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request"}.

[Find the screenshot for reference]
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tbFm.png

Comment: Did you follow this document(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-wns-push-notification)?

Comment: Yes. But i didn't registered in Windows dev center & create an app in Windows Store. I started directly creating a notification hub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure the Windows(WNS) under Notification Settings first. You can follow this document(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-wns-push-notification#configure-wns-settings-for-the-hub)
[image]

I have tested it on my side, after following all the steps in the document, it works fine.
[image]

Comment: If you’re Microsoft partner, I find a free channel to solve azure queries: aka.ms/devchat. They support online chat and email.

Comment: How can i configure WNS settings for the hub without having a developer account? I don't have Package SID & Security Key to update WNS.

Comment: You need to sign up a developer account first and create a app in windows store by following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-wns-push-notification#create-an-app-in-windows-store. Then you will get the Package SID&Security Key.

Comment: I've tried to sign up. It's not free, To register i have to pay money.

Comment: Yes. Individual accounts cost approximately $19 USD, and company accounts cost approximately $99 USD (the exact amounts may vary depending on your country or region). This is a one-time registration fee and no renewal is required.